# Converting OCaml to F#: Converting OCaml open_box and close_box to F#

Tags: f#, ocaml

I am converting several modules based on OCaml to F# and ran into the OCaml print formatting functions [open_box and close_box](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html) from the OCaml format module. After reading about the concept of a printing box, it makes sense but seems like it needs a lot of work behind the scenes to implement.

Is there an F# module that is functionally equivalent?

If not, without having to convert portions of the OCaml format module, what are quick and simple replacement functions?

EDIT

[Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197411/jack-p) has a version as part of OCaml Format at [FSharpx.Compatibility.OCaml.Format.Format.fs](https://github.com/jack-pappas/FSharpx.Compatibility/blob/master/FSharpx.Compatibility.OCaml.Format/Format.fs) 
I havent' tested it, but it is the most compelete version I have found at present.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it under F#?  May compile directly without modification.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci The format module needs other modules and conversions to work with F#. I spent about 15 minutes on it, but it is turning into a cascade of errors that I don't want to chase down since I don't know how many exist.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Very little compiles without modifications now and the `Format` module required hundreds of changes. Indexing arrays uses `xs.(i)` in OCaml and `xs.[i]` in F# with a type annotation. The original code uses OCaml's streams for which there is no equivalent in F#. Channels are equivalent to text readers and writers but require some tweaks. Even `printf` works differently!

Comment: @JonHarrop I think it's always worth a quick try--won't hurt anything and will give a person a general feel for how much work is going to be involved.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I found it quite unpredictable actually. Like the OP, I saw hundreds of errors from the compiler and thought about running a mile. But when you knuckle down on it you can actually plough through them at quite a rate because they're almost all trivial changes.

Comment: @JonHarrop I might do it, but how did you handle the OCaml streams you mentioned?

Comment: @GuyCoder I converted it to an F# `Seq`. I may actually be thinking of the wrong code base though. I translated some other OCaml code to F# for a client recently...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an F# module that is functionally equivalent?

No.

> If not, without having to convert portions of the OCaml format module, what are quick and simple replacement functions?

Nothing beyond `printf`. However, I had to translate the `Format` module from OCaml to F# recently and it only took a couple of hours.